# Select and sort rows of a data frame based on a vector

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(Term = structure(c(6L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction", 
"cellular response to cytokine stimulus", "negative regulation of multi-organism process", 
"positive regulation of biological process", "positive regulation of multicellular organismal process", 
"regulation of viral process"), class = "factor"), c = c(10.698, 
24.445, 0, 12.058, 9.542, 0), d = c(0, 7.093, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Term", 
"c", "d"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(154L, 147L, 105L, 
157L, 86L, 104L))
```

That looks like this:

```
> df
                                                       Term      c     d
154                             regulation of viral process 10.698 0.000
147                  cellular response to cytokine stimulus 24.445 7.093
105               positive regulation of biological process  0.000 0.000
157           negative regulation of multi-organism process 12.058 0.000
86                   Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction  9.542 0.000
104 positive regulation of multicellular organismal process  0.000 0.000
```

What I want to do is given a list of vector:

```
 target <- c("Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction","negative regulation of multi-organism process ")
```

I want to select and sort the `df$Term` based on `target`.
Resulting in this data frame

```
                                                Term      c     d
              Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction  9.542 0.000
       negative regulation of multi-organism process 12.058 0.000
```

But why this command failed?

```
> df[match(target,df$Term),]
                                     Term     c  d
86 Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction 9.542  0
NA                                   <NA>    NA NA
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: `target[2]` ends with a white space.

Answer (score 1):

You erroneusly put a space at the end of

```
target <- c("Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction","negative regulation of multi-organism process ") # <--- this space after process
```

hence the vectors don't match :)

Indeed, the following code does work:

```
df <- structure(list(Term = structure(c(6L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L), 
                                  .Label = c("Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction", 
                                  "cellular response to cytokine stimulus", 
                                  "negative regulation of multi-organism process", 
                                  "positive regulation of biological process", "positive regulation of multicellular organismal process", "regulation of viral process"), class = "factor"), c = c(10.698, 
                                                                                                                                 24.445, 0, 12.058, 9.542, 0), d = c(0, 7.093, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Term", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        "c", "d"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(154L, 147L, 105L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       157L, 86L, 104L))

target <- c("Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction","negative regulation of multi-organism process")

df[df$Term %in% target,]
```